# Using a singleton as a primitive alternative to Memcached/Redis

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, memcached, redis

I am building a web/mobile application that will be used as a hobby-related data portal that imports data from a 3rd party web service and then allows the user to customize and filter its view according to preferences.  The data retrieved from outside is not editable by the user -- you can think of it as almost stock quotes that change every so often but it is not stock quotes.  It is organized in categories (each category being a U.S. state), each category having on average 500 lines of data with only a few attributes in each.  However, each user's view can and most likely will encompass (get data from) different categories.

There is a backend job that updates this data in MySQL every 10 min.  However, when a user wants to retrieve it, considering the performance of disk I/O and the nature, dynamics, and size of this data, it would clearly make sense to store it in some form of in-memory container for front-end application use rather than reading it from the DB evert request, i.e. cache it.  So when this job runs, after storing the data in the DB, it would update the memory store if the front end server is running.

I am familiar with products such as Memcached and Redis but since the data structure is fairly simple, I was wondering about the pros and cons of using a lighter alternative, e.g. a Singleton object within Glassfish, which serves a RESTful API to both the web and mobile app.

Thanks

Comment: The main difficulty is the concurrency handling. You'll have one thread modifying the data structurs while several other threads read in it. If you're in Glassfish, have you considered using JPA with a second-level cache? You would get automatic cache updates, while still be able to perform database queries (whose results could be cached as well). And the concurrency would be handled by the cache and the JPA provider.

Comment: how expensive do you think it will be to lock each cached record for new read while its update takes place?  allowing a dirty read for the threads that have already begun reading.

Comment: You mean, if you use a second-level cache? I don't know. It would depend on the cache implementation.